# Xcode, Swift Could not cast value of type '__NSCFNumber' (0x7fff87c511a0) to 'NSString' (0x7fff87d0eee8)

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode

Im facing with error : `Could not cast value of type '__NSCFNumber' (0x7fff87c511a0) to 'NSString' (0x7fff87d0eee8).`

```
the line : self.setNewMessagesCount(newMessagesCount: Int((Response["newMessagesCount"] as? String)!)!)
```

what im doing wrong? (im using newer version of xcode)

thank you for help and have a good day! :)

Comment: The error is pretty clear. The value for key `newMessagesCount` – as the name implies – is a number (most likely `Int`)

Comment: thanks for answer, how should i add it in this line ? or replace the line?

Answer (score 2):

The phrase `Int((Response["newMessagesCount"] as? String)!)!` means:

1. look up the value for the key `"newMessagesCount"` in `Response`;
2. check whether that's a `String`, if so then keep a `String` reference to it, otherwise keep `nil`;
3. the first `!` then says "oh, but I assume I didn't get `nil` even though I allowed for it just then, act as if I definitely have a reference to a `String` now, otherwise raise an exception";
4. the `Int` wrapping then attempts to parse what you've now guaranteed is a `String` to an `Int`;
5. the final `!` then basically says: assume that conversion definitely worked, and raise an exception if not.

So you might at least neaten that to:

```
Int(Response["newMessagesCount"] as! String)!
```

... but it looks like you're parsing content you've received from elsewhere, so actually the error is in using `!` at all, anywhere, since you're failing to validate your input.

You probably want something more like:

```
if let newMessagesCountResponse = Response["newMessagesCount"] as? String, 
   let newMessagesCount = Int(newMessagesCountResponse) {
   print("\(newMessagesCount) new messages")
} else {
   print("newMessagesCount wasn't present in the dictionary,",
         "or its value wasn't a string,",
         "or the string couldn't be parsed as an int")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I used it and its works but its not update the new message, for exaple, if i sending from another device message to this im getting notification but cant read the message that sent from another device, only if im refresh it manually have you some idea how can figure it?

Comment: Are you displaying anything in the `else` case above? If so, and judging by your original post, I think possibly it's just that "newMessagesCount" isn't actually a string, it's a number. So then you could simplify all the way to `if let newMessagesCount = Response["newMessagesCount"] as? Int {`

Comment: Brilliant! its made it simple, but the problem its not updating it self, can i add something to push it update self when im getting massage?